# Problema con formulario Ajax en Plantilla Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

Cómo puedo acceder al diccionario si django hace que la clave sea única, ya que es necesario enviar un json con arrays?

Este es mi código Ajax en una plantilla Django

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function RegistrarAperturacaja(){
    alert($("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val());
    var datos = {
        aperturacaja:[
        {
        fechaaperturacaja: "",
        caja_idcaja: $("#cmbCaja").val(),
        detalleaperturacaja: $("#descaperturacaja").val(),
        estadoaperturacaja: 1,
        activoaperturacaja: 1,        
        montoaperturacaja: $("#txtMontoApertura").val(),

        }] ,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
    };  

    var sendData = JSON.stringify(datos);

    $.ajax({
        url: strRootUrl+"/insertaraperturacaja/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        data: sendData,

        success: function(msg) {

                alert("Se Registro correctamente la Apertura de Caja");

        }
    });

}
```

Django View al hace ->print request.POST

```
<QueryDict: {u'aperturacaja[0][detalleaperturacaja]': [u'asd '], u'aperturacaja[0][caja_idcaja]': [u'1'], u'aperturacaja[0][activoaperturacaja]': [u'1'], u'aperturacaja[0][fechaaperturacaja]': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'kqmnDQCA5qW98HpQFmqewoaRaPB10WNV'], u'aperturacaja[0][montoaperturacaja]': [u'11'], u'aperturacaja[0][estadoaperturacaja]': [u'1']}>
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder al diccionario si la clave me la hace una sola, ya que es necesario enviar un json con arrays?

Comment: ¿Que elemento del diccionario exactamente quieres acceder?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto:

```
Diccionario = dict(DiccionarioJSON.iterlists())
```

- [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) toma un par( llave, valor) y lo convierte en un
  diccionario.
- [queryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) es un tipo de estructura de datos usada
  en Django donde el metodo `iterlists()` regresa donde incluye los
  valores como una lista. DiccionarioJSON es un queryDict y Diccionario
  es un diccionario de python.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar tu respuesta?

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego, pero estaba confundiendo de como enviar un array con un abjeto por ajax, y es que el decorador @csrf_exempt me solucionó el problema 403 para poder enviar un json y solo hacer un  data        = json.loads(request.body)